# Inheritance of class template - base class fields access

Tags: c++

Trying to write class which inherits from class template. Then access a field declared in base. But it does not even compile. Maybe a c++ standard problem?

I have tried something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Base {
public:
    T xxx;
};

template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T> {
public:
    T getval() { return xxx; }
};
```

Compiler error is: `error: ‘xxx’ was not declared in this scope`

```
   11 |         T getval() { return xxx; }
      |                             ^~~
```

But when I changed method in Derived to `T getval() { return Base<T>::xxx; }` then it compiles without error.

Comment: duplicate is about "why `this->xxx` is needed?" but the reasoning for why `Base<T>::xxx` fixes the error is the same